# Numpy indexing: Getting a specific row for each column

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

For example:

```
A = np.random.randn(4,32)
inds = np.random.randint(4,size=32)
res = A[inds,np.arange(32)]
```

This gets the desired result, but is rather cumbersome. Is there simpler way to get this behavior? (e.g. using advanced indexing)

Comment: So, what's the name of the operation that you are doing with `A[inds,np.arange(32)]`?

Comment: Hint: It rhymes with "emplacement"

Comment: `inds` holds an array of desired rows, one for each column. Just performing `A[inds]` results in getting *all* columns for each desired row, hence the need to use `np.arange`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry, I don't follow :(

Comment: Did you read up on [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)? Do you see anything that matches up with your existing code?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I looked over that page and nothing immediately jumped out at me. I understand that this question apparently has a simple solution that am not getting. Could you please just tell me instead of hinting at it?

Comment: You already have `advanced indexing` in your code.

Comment: @Divakar Are you saying that my way of doing this is already the simplest way?

Comment: "Simplest/elegant/fanciful/most-readable/cleanest" I don't know how to truly measure those. If you are talking about performance, yes this is it.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you. I realize that I was already using advanced indexing. I was under the impression that "advanced indexing" wasn't a monolithic expression, such that there could be *another* way of using it that was simpler (e.g. no call to np.arange). I take it the answer is "no" -- I really wish you'd have just said that up front.

Answer (score 0):

```
inds = np.random.randint(4,size=32)
result=[]
for i in range(0,len(inds):
    result.append(A[inds[i],i])
    print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = A[inds,np.arange(32)]
```

The above is exactly using numpy advanced indexing with inds being the row indices and np.arange(32) being the column indices to be extracted.

What's your more advanced solution like?